# How to lock excel aspect/visual options

Tags: vba, excel, aspect-ratio

I am trying to lock the aspect/visual options of an excel file, so when other people open it, it remains as I set and cannot change it.
When I set the aspect options and other people open it in their PCs, all settings are gone.

I would like to set the aspect as the following:

- Do not show formula bar
- Do not show headings
- Minimize the Ribbon

Additionally I would like to lock specific settings for each sheet:

Zoom:

- 100% for sheet 1 and 4
- 90% for sheet 2 and 3

Freeze panes:

- Unfreeze for sheet 1 and 4
- Freeze the first 3 columns for sheet 2 and 3

Is there anyway of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used this in the 'thisworkbook' excel object. The send keys worked but i would be careful as these are prone to errors.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

If ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1" Or ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet4" Then
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 90
ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet2" Or ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet3" Then
    Columns("d:d").Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 90
End If

Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False

If Application.CommandBars("Ribbon").Height >= 150 Then
    SendKeys "^{F1}"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I have added

ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1

To be on top of the page.
The command for hide Ribbon is not working in my laptop.

Comment: replace the last if statement with, hopefully this should work!                             Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"

Comment: That one hides everything.

I have used
CommandBars.ExecuteMso "MinimizeRibbon"

and it works if used after
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will work, if not let me know!

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

If ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1" Or ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet4" Then
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 90
ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet2" Or ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet3" Then
    Columns("d:d").Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 90
End If

Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1

End Sub
```